# Set custom quantity arguments to products from specific category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, product-quantity

i'm trying to set a minimum order quantity for a specific category in my woocommerce store. I've written a piece of code but it seems like the minimum quantity in the cart applies to ALL categories and not only to the one i've set up ("nettoyage") ... What did i do wrong ?

Here's my code (from my `functions.php`) :

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'bloomer_woocommerce_quantity_changes', 10, 2);

function bloomer_woocommerce_quantity_changes($args, $product)
{
    if (!is_cart()) {
        if (is_singular('product') && (has_term('nettoyage', 'product_cat'))) {

            $args['input_value'] = 3; // Start from this value (default = 1)
            $args['max_value'] = 10; // Max quantity (default = -1)
            $args['min_value'] = 3; // Min quantity (default = 0)
            $args['step'] = 1; // Increment/decrement by this value (default = 1)

        }
    }

    return $args;
}

function sww_check_category_for_minimum()
{
    // set the minimum quantity in the category to purchase
    $min_quantity = 3;

    // set the id of the category for which we're requiring a minimum quantity
    $category_id = 40;

    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term($category_id, 'product_cat');
    $category_name = '<a href="' . get_term_link($category_id, 'product_cat') . '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';

    // get the quantity category in the cart
    $category_quantity = sww_get_category_quantity_in_cart($category_id);

    if ($category_quantity < $min_quantity) {
        // render a notice to explain the minimum
        wc_add_notice(sprintf('You must order at least 3 products from the %2$s category to be able to order!', $min_quantity, $category_name), 'error');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sww_check_category_for_minimum');

//Returns the quantity of products from a given category in the WC cart
function sww_get_category_quantity_in_cart($category_id)
{
    // get the quantities of cart items to check against
    $quantities = WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities();

    // start a counter for the quantity of items from this category
    $category_quantity = 0;

    // loop through cart items to check the product categories
    foreach ($quantities as $product_id => $quantity) {

        $product_categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

        // check the categories for our desired one
        foreach ($product_categories as $category) {

            // if we find it, add the line item quantity to the category total
            if ($category_id === $category->term_id) {
                $category_quantity += $quantity;
            }
        }
    }

    return $category_quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead *(that will not requires any check)*:

```
// General quantity settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){
    if ( has_term( array('nettoyage'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        if( ! is_cart() ) {
            $args['input_value'] = 3; // Starting value
        }
        $args['min_value'] = 3; // Minimum value
        $args['max_value'] = 10; // Maximum value
    }
    return $args;
}

// For Ajax add to cart button (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg', 10, 2 );
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg( $args, $product ) {
    if ( has_term( array('nettoyage'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $args['quantity'] = 3; // Min value
    }
    return $args;
}

// For product variations (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_available_variation_min_qty', 10, 3);
function custom_available_variation_min_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    if ( has_term( array('nettoyage'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $args['min_qty'] = 3; // Min value
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

**Note:** The category "nettoyage" need to be set up for each desired product. If not it will not work.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot mate!! (and it's a lot cleaner)